# How can I disable an https redirect on Apache on Ubuntu on AWS EC2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I need to disable a previously configured https redirect on an apache ubuntu on Amazon Web Services EC2 node.  I believe it has been done on the apache .htaccess level.  However, I have checked the .htaccess and disabled the following lines like so:

```
# Force https connection, not http.
# Disabled due to issues on tracking referrers - now done
# through PHP
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I have restarted Apache.  I am still getting a redirect.

Subsequently I have started to look in other areas where this is being triggered.

I have checked the regular config files of Apache.
I have checked config files of "sites-enabled" and "sites-avalable" for that virtual host
I have checked the load balancers on AWS.
I have checked for the following lines in any config

```
Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
```

The only thing that might be related that I don't understand fully is the following line under ssl config for that virtual host, but I don't think it is causing this.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
```

I have run the following command for restart

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Is there something I am missing?
What I am looking for is some suggestions or direction on how I perhaps might be able to debug where this is being triggered so that I can disable this.  I have a sneaking suspicion I will smack my head when someone helps me find an answer.

Thank you kindly in advance for your help.

Comment: The comment says that https redirection is now being done via PHP. Are you sure the PHP redirection has been disabled?

Comment: This is how I disabled it... it's my comment I put in there. I think I found the issue in the default config file in "sites-enabled".  I had missed this file but had checked all other config files that I could think of.  So for anyone else that might have a similar issue, I would recommend to look for a "default" file within any directories included within the main config file.  Now I am dealing with another issue related to this...  Thank you for looking at this and trying to help!